# Fixing background color of labels in output cell

Tags: labeling, stylesheet

I swear that I have asked or at least seen a similar question before, but I cannot find it.

I tend to use the Report/StandardReport stylesheet because the color difference between input and output cells is extremely convenient. However, I frequently have issues with labels in plots maintaining some of the gray background even when I place them in a `Panel` or a `Manipulate` (white background), and even when I specify white backgrounds for everything I can think of. For example:

```
Panel@AngularGauge[0.5, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Background -> White], 
                   ScaleOrigin -> {π, 0}, Background -> White, 
                   GaugeLabels -> "Label"]
```

[image]

Notice the gray at the top of Label. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this example, the problem is that the label is placed into the graphic using an [`InsetBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InsetBox) (probably coming from a [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text) object), and this [`InsetBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InsetBox) is inheriting the main background color. You can fix this by adding a [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle) option:

```
AngularGauge[
    0.5,
    ScaleOrigin->{π,0},
    Background->White,
    GaugeLabels->"Label",
    BaseStyle->{InsetBoxOptions->{Background->White}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly; thank you!